# Can't change Emacs's default indentation between HTML tags

Tags: emacs, indentation

I'm confused about the Emacs indentation paradigm.

I have this in my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq-default tab-width 4)
```

If I press TAB in the following situation

```
                    <ul>
(caret)
                    </ul>
```

it end up like this

```
                   <ul>
                     (caret)
                   </ul>
```

(with 2 spaces indentation between the HTML tags.)

It should end up like this:

```
                   <ul>
                       (caret)
                   </ul>
```

I tried everything:

```
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq tab-stop-list '(4 8 12 16))
```

I've set every possible Emacs setting about indentation to 4 but that 2 space indentation is still there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which mode are you using to edit HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's the default mode I guess (I thought Emacs change to html mode when it opens a file with .html extension)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Setting the tab width isn't applicable in this scenario, but I understand your confusion; Emacs provides several tab-related variables and determining the correct one for a particular scenario can be confusing.

[This EmacsWiki article provides more details about setting the indentation level for HTML](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingHtml); in general, [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/) is a great resource for Emacs tips.

In this specific case, since you're using Emacs' standard HTML mode (`html-mode`, as defined by `sgml-mode`), the variable that you want to set is `sgml-basic-offset`.  That variable defaults to 2, but you can change it to 4 as follows:

```
(setq sgml-basic-offset 4)
```

To make this change specific only to `html-mode`, you can use the following code:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    ;; Default indentation is usually 2 spaces, changing to 4.
    (set (make-local-variable 'sgml-basic-offset) 4)))
```

This all assumes that you're using Emacs 22 or later; if that's not the case, the EmacsWiki page that I linked to contains a workaround for earlier versions of Emacs.

Comment: It worked thanks! I'm curious why not:
(setq html-basic-offset 4)?

Comment: HTML is a derivative of SGML.  The Emacs functionality for `html-mode` is provided by a general-purpose SGML package, which is why the variable is `sgml-basic-offset`.  This is why it's better to set that variable in the `html-mode-hook`; that way, it will only affect HTML files, and not SGML files in general.

Comment: This would depend on which mode you're using to edit your HTML code. There's no real *default* as such.

Comment: Tried this in 25.2.2. The second snippet didn't work, the first one did.

Comment: The above code is working, but ``html`` should be changed with ``mhtml``.